Can I use files/folders copied from a CD to create a valid ISO file?
I don't own a CD/DVD drive, but I know enough to be dangerous. I used the library's drive to upload all the files from the CD to my google drive and I wanted to produce an ISO file to access from my win10 laptop hard drive.
Did I make a basic mistake by not making an ISO directly from the CD, or do I have a path forward that at least makes the executable's work to gain access to the proprietary data (medical images)?  If I must make the ISO directly from the CD, does win 10 have the native ability to do this or is there a third party product to use?  fyi-I cannot load software onto this machine.
I see that the files included an autorun.inf.  I assume that since this image would be on my hard drive autorun won't be invoked. To run the program do I try running the other .exe files found in that same root directory?  Since the CD/DVD structure was not flat, not all files are in the root directory.
How do I ensure the iso file is created, so the program works correctly?

It mostly depends on what kind of CD it was. Yes, imaging directly - also assuming that there aren't weird copy protection methods at play - would work as the original either when burned to media or directly mounted as a virtual one (any OS can do this, "natively" or via 3rd party tools/software). Have you already tested and found a problem or aren't just asking about hypotheticals? If the latter then please don't.

If it's a bootable CD, an ISO can be created, it simply depends on the OS it's booting. If it's a data CD, Windows natively includes the ability to create an ISO from a directory's contents, otherwise there are third party programs that can do the same (both free and licensed). ISOs use specific filesystems for disc media that have pros/cons, so depending on usage, a VHD could also be created to copy the data to, or if wanting parity, the directory can be captured as a WIM (/CaptureDir:"Z:\Path\to\Directory")

For most CDs this should be possible: They're just a collection of files/data within a generalized structure that has a few rules. Some CDs may have some unique properties as part of a copy-protection scheme which would not be captured in a simple file copy, and would definitely be lost in the various file movements you've done so far.
For most CDs there's no need to have an actual CD or ISO or anything else. All you need are all the files from that CD in the same relative folder structure.
You can figure out which executable needs to be run by opening the autorun.inf file in Notepad. Inside will be a few short strings of information, one possibly talking about an icon file, and another containing a path to one of the executables in the disk path.
